# VSCode Tab to Rulers

Tags: visual-studio-code

Lately I've been programming a lot of assembly, and for those unfamilar you have to layout certain lines at certain widths to write good code.

I've already setup some rulers to help guide me:
[image]

The problem is that theres no common factor small enough so I have to space out to each ruler (or tabs set = to 1) to write at those lines.

Is there any way to immediately tab to where the ruler is? Or a specific col? It would save me a lot of time.